# Proof by contradiction by first assuming proposition true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In a proof by contradiction, we first assume a proposition $P$ false, then prove some known truth to be false, then that would imply the assumption $P$ should really be true.

> Do we really need to first assume the proposition $P$ false?

It seems it's okay to first assume proposition $P =$ true, derive some known truth to be false, then we know $P$ should really be false.

Is it the case??

Thanks

Comment: You can prove either way. All you need is to arrive at a statement that contradicts your earlier assumption.

Answer (score 5):

We are considering the two methods of proof:

(1) To prove $P$, we assume $\neg P$ and derive a contradiction.

(2) To prove $\neg P$, we assume $P$ and derive a contradiction.

Both methods are valid, although in general (1) requires the Law of Excluded Middle to conclude $P$ from $\neg\neg P$.  In my opinion, only method (1) is properly called "proof by contradiction."  Method (2) is simply the ordinary way of proving a negation.  Indeed, the negation $\neg P$ is sometimes *defined* as a shorthand for the implication $P \implies \bot$.

EDIT: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#In_mathematical_logic) both methods (1) and (2) are properly called "proof by contradiction."